# Pandas groupby each date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which has data like:

```
date        dept1  dept2 dept3
1/5/2018      5      3    0
2/5/2018      12     8    6
3/5/2018       7     10   9
```

I have read this data into  a dataframe:

```
dept_df = pd.read_csv('dept_sales.csv')
```

I have to group this department sales figure every day like and sort in descending order:

```
  Date       dept1  dept2 dept3
1/5/2018      5      3     0
2/5/2018      17     11    6
3/5/2018      24     21    15
```

Comment: look at [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Comment: @anky  yes, dept_df.cumsum() works but it also sums the Date field. How to exclude it from cumsum ?

Comment: may be set date as index: `df.set_index('date').cumsum()` , if you want date as column reset the index back: `df.set_index('date').cumsum().reset_index()`

Comment: @anky. Worked like  a charm. Now how can I draw a line graph using this data with department and date as axis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cumsum method for that:

```
dept_df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'dept1': 'cumsum', 'dept2': 'cumsum', 'dept3': 'cumsum'})
```